# Lines and circles are not visible. Why not?

Tags: diagrams

I'm running TeXworks and MikTeX on Microsoft Windows and within a document I have the code you see below.  Compiling results in a pdf file in which I can see the text within this picture but I can't see the line or the circles.  Nonetheless when I print it the line and the circles are there.  Is there something I can do differently to make the line and the circles visible?

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.66mm}

\begin{picture}(100,100)(0,0)

\label{picture of bitangent plane}

\put(40,50){\circle{60}}      % left big circle

\put(140,50){\circle{60}}     % right big circle

\put(122,74){\circle*{2}}     % dot at e^{i\theta} on right circle

\put(122,26){\circle*{2}}     % dot at e^{-i\theta} on right circle

\put(58,26){\circle*{2}}      % dot at e^{-i\theta} on left circle

\put(70,50){\circle*{2}}      % dot at -1 on left circle

\put(38,11){\line(4,3){104}}  % line

\put(140,80){\circle*{2}}     % dot at i on right circle

\put(140,20){\circle*{2}}     % dot at -i on right circle

\put(170,50){\circle*{2}}     % dot at 1 on right circle

\put(110,50){\circle*{2}}     % dot at -1 on right circle

\put(10,50){\circle*{2}}      % dot at 1 on left circle

\put(40,80){\circle*{2}}      % dot at i on left circle

\put(40,20){\circle*{2}}      % dot at -i on left circle

\put(58,74){\circle*{2}}      % dot at e^{i\theta} on left circle

\put(116,76){$e^{i\theta}$}   % right

\put(115,19){$e^{-i\theta}$}  % right

\put(62,76){$e^{i\theta}$}

\put(59,19){$e^{-i\theta}$}   % left

\put(173,49){$1$}  \put(5,49){$1$}

\put(101,49){$-1$} \put(72,49){$-1$}

\put(140,83){$i$}  \put(40,83){$i$}

\put(137,14){$-i$} \put(35,14){$-i$}

\put(70,5){\text{The bitangent plane.}}

\end{picture}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your circles are too small and you get warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 7.
```

Load the `pict2e` package.

I also fixed the bounding box and put the picture in a `figure` environment. Your `\label` command is out of place where you put it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.66mm}
\begin{picture}(180,100)(0,0)
\put(40,50){\circle{60}}      % left big circle
\put(140,50){\circle{60}}     % right big circle
\put(122,74){\circle*{2}}     % dot at e^{i\theta} on right circle
\put(122,26){\circle*{2}}     % dot at e^{-i\theta} on right circle
\put(58,26){\circle*{2}}      % dot at e^{-i\theta} on left circle
\put(70,50){\circle*{2}}      % dot at -1 on left circle
\put(38,11){\line(4,3){104}}  % line
\put(140,80){\circle*{2}}     % dot at i on right circle
\put(140,20){\circle*{2}}     % dot at -i on right circle
\put(170,50){\circle*{2}}     % dot at 1 on right circle
\put(110,50){\circle*{2}}     % dot at -1 on right circle
\put(10,50){\circle*{2}}      % dot at 1 on left circle
\put(40,80){\circle*{2}}      % dot at i on left circle
\put(40,20){\circle*{2}}      % dot at -i on left circle
\put(58,74){\circle*{2}}      % dot at e^{i\theta} on left circle
\put(116,76){$e^{i\theta}$}   % right
\put(115,19){$e^{-i\theta}$}  % right
\put(62,76){$e^{i\theta}$}
\put(59,19){$e^{-i\theta}$}   % left
\put(173,49){$1$}  \put(5,49){$1$}
\put(101,49){$-1$} \put(72,49){$-1$}
\put(140,83){$i$}  \put(40,83){$i$}
\put(137,14){$-i$} \put(35,14){$-i$}
\end{picture}
\caption{The bitangent plane}\label{fig:bitangentplane}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

LaTeX's `picture` environment only supports a limited range of slopes and radii, because circles and lines are constructed using font glyphs:

```
LaTeX Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 9.
```

Package `pict2e` circumvent these limitations by using graphics commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.66mm}
\begin{picture}(175,90)(5,3)
\label{picture of bitangent plane}
\put(40,50){\circle{60}}      % left big circle
\put(140,50){\circle{60}}     % right big circle
\put(122,74){\circle*{2}}     % dot at e^{i\theta} on right circle
\put(122,26){\circle*{2}}     % dot at e^{-i\theta} on right circle
\put(58,26){\circle*{2}}      % dot at e^{-i\theta} on left circle
\put(70,50){\circle*{2}}      % dot at -1 on left circle
\put(38,11){\line(4,3){104}}  % line
\put(140,80){\circle*{2}}     % dot at i on right circle
\put(140,20){\circle*{2}}     % dot at -i on right circle
\put(170,50){\circle*{2}}     % dot at 1 on right circle
\put(110,50){\circle*{2}}     % dot at -1 on right circle
\put(10,50){\circle*{2}}      % dot at 1 on left circle
\put(40,80){\circle*{2}}      % dot at i on left circle
\put(40,20){\circle*{2}}      % dot at -i on left circle
\put(58,74){\circle*{2}}      % dot at e^{i\theta} on left circle
\put(116,76){$e^{i\theta}$}   % right
\put(115,19){$e^{-i\theta}$}  % right
\put(62,76){$e^{i\theta}$}
\put(59,19){$e^{-i\theta}$}   % left
\put(173,49){$1$}  \put(5,49){$1$}
\put(101,49){$-1$} \put(72,49){$-1$}
\put(140,83){$i$}  \put(40,83){$i$}
\put(137,14){$-i$} \put(35,14){$-i$}
\put(70,5){\text{The bitangent plane.}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And for fun, a [golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) version for [The Last Error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161718/lines-and-circles-are-not-visible-why-not/161720?noredirect=1#comment370449_161720):

```
\documentclass{book}\usepackage{pict2e}\begin{document}\def~#1,#2
{\p#1,#2{\circle*{2}}}\def\p#1,#2#{\put(#1,#2)}\def\m#1,#2,#3 #4
{\p#1,#3{#4}\p#2,#3{#4}}\unitlength0.66mm\picture(170,87)~53,23
\m35,135,47 \circle{60} \p33,8{\line(4,3){104}}~117,71 ~117,23 ~65,47
~135,77 ~135,17 ~165,47 ~105,47 ~5,47 ~35,77 ~35,17 ~53,71 \m57,111,73
$e^{i\theta}$ \m54,110,16 $e^{-i\theta}$ \m0,168,46 $1$ \m67,96,46 $-1$
\m35,135,80 $i$ \m30,132,11 $-i$
\p65,2{The bitangent plane.}\endpicture\end{document}
```

Comment: @TheLastError: 516 characters.

Comment: @TheLastError: Reduced to 495 characters.

Answer (score 10):

A solution where only the center of the circles and the radius is defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\psset{unit=0.66mm} \def\CRadius{30 }
\begin{pspicture}(175,70)
\pnodes(40,35){M1}(140,35){M2}
\pscircle(M1){\CRadius}      % left big circle
\pscircle(M2){\CRadius}     % right big circle
\psCircleTangents(M1){\CRadius}(M2){\CRadius}%
\psdots(CircleTO1)(CircleTO2)(CircleTO3)(CircleTO4)%
       (CircleTI1)(CircleTI2)(CircleTI3)(CircleTI4)
\rput(M1){\psdots(\CRadius;180)(\CRadius;0)}
\rput(M2){\psdots(\CRadius;180)(\CRadius;0)}
\pcline[nodesep=-17,linecolor=red](CircleTI3)(CircleTI4)%
\uput[45](CircleTI1){$e^{i\theta}$}  \uput[135](CircleTI4){$e^{i\theta}$}
\uput[225](CircleTI2){$e^{-i\theta}$}\uput[-45](CircleTI3){$e^{-i\theta}$}
\uput[180](!\psGetNodeCenter{M1}M1.x \CRadius sub M1.y){1} 
\uput[0](!\psGetNodeCenter{M1}M1.x \CRadius add M1.y){-1} 
\uput[180](!\psGetNodeCenter{M2}M2.x \CRadius sub M2.y){-1} 
\uput[0](!\psGetNodeCenter{M2}M2.x \CRadius add M2.y){1} 
\uput[90](CircleTO1){$i$}  \uput[90](CircleTO2){$i$}
\uput[-90](CircleTO3){$-i$}\uput[-90](CircleTO4){$-i$}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The bitangent plane}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
  \foreach \ang/\x in {0/$-1$,45/$e^{i\theta}$,90/$i$,180/$1$,270/$-i$,315/$e^{-i\theta}$}{%
   \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt] (a\ang) at (\ang:2cm) {};
   \node  at (\ang:2.4cm) {\x};
  }
  \draw (5.7,0) circle [radius=2cm];
  \foreach \ang/\x in {0/$1$,135/$e^{i\theta}$,90/$i$,180/$-1$,270/$-i$,225/$e^{-i\theta}$}{%
   \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt] (b\ang) at ([xshift=5.7cm]\ang:2cm) {};
   \node  at ([xshift=5.7cm]\ang:2.4cm) {\x};
  }
  \draw[shorten >=-2cm,shorten <=-2cm] (a315) -- (b135);
  \node at (3,-3) {The bitangent plane.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TheLastError Do you have a counter? We don't compete with `pstricks` in this aspect ;)

Comment: http://www.charactercountonline.com/ is my counter.

Answer (score 4):

Reducing the number of used characters in the existing answers.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=9,unit=3}
\degrees[8]
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Right[2][1 1]{%
    \psscalebox{#1}{%
    \rput(!2 sqrt 0){\curvepnodes{0}{8}{1 t \pst@angleunit PtoC}{#2}\pscircle{1}}%
    \foreach \i/\t in {0/1,2/i,3/e^{i\theta},4/-1,5/e^{-i\theta},6/-i}{\qdisk(#2\i){2pt}\uput[\i](#2\i){\psscalebox{#1}{$\t$}}}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-1.5)(2.5,1.5)
    \Right{A}\Right[-1 1]{B}\pcline[nodesep=-1](A3)(B5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Golfed version (446 characters)

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}\usepackage{pstricks-add}\degrees[8]\makeatletter\def\R#1#2{\psscalebox{#1}{\rput(!2 sqrt 3 mul 0){\curvepnodes[plotpoints=9]{0}{8}{3 t \pst@angleunit PtoC}{#2}\pscircle{3}}\foreach \i/\t in {0/1,2/i,3/e^{i\theta},4/-1,5/e^{-i\theta},6/-i}{\qdisk(#2\i){.1}\uput[\i](#2\i){\psscalebox{#1}{$\t$}}}}}\begin{document}\pspicture(-9,-5)(9,5)\R{1 1}{A}\R{-1 1}{B}\pcline[nodesep=-1](A3)(B5)\endpspicture\end{document}
```

Comment: In search of less characters don't lose the code readability a good balance is imp. can you make the code with new line instead of single line.

Comment: @texenthusiast: The golfed version is not for readability but for fun. It should be ignored by those who are not interested in golfing.

Answer (score 1):

Golfing ? 303 characters with tikz.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\draw foreach\i in
{1,-1}{[xscale=\i,xshift=2.8cm](0,0)circle(2)foreach~in{-,}{foreach\k/\p in
{~1/~90-90,~i/~90,$e^{~i\theta}$/~135}{(\p:2)node[scale=3](\i\p){.}(\p:2.4)node{\k}}}};
\draw[shorten >=-2cm,shorten <=-2cm](1135)--(-1-135);}\end{document}
```

[image]